# How to use one boot partition for AVLinux / Dual Boot

Tags: debian, multi-boot, dualboot

I am running Windows 10 on my drive, and want to additionally install AVLinux. In the installation process I select a 1GB partition I prepared for booting (as I want to encrypt the Linux partition, this is apperantly needed).

[image: Partioning]

[image: Partition Choices]

When starting the installation, while the partitions are being set up I am asked what partition to use for GRUB Windows/Linux dual boot, but I cannot select the previously mentioned 1GB partition.

[image: Installation Start]

[image: BootChoices]

I am unsure as to what to do (as I am just starting with Linux, I have no experience in what is what on this side).

Wouldn't one boot partition suffice? I can only choose the old Windows boot partition (like it says in the help box), but why the Linux Boot partition then?

Comment: Everything looks good here. You need a boot partition (your 1GB) to handle the encryption layer for your main system _and_ a grub partition (the EFI one, currently booting just Windows) to manage the initial pre-boot process. It _is_ confusing, I agree.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The installer actually forced me to setup a boot partition (due to the encryption), so I had done that. It was 1Gb large. You can see it in the last entry of the second screenshot. I had tried several times with the install, but since I couldn't boot into my linux partition, I ended up installing it on a separate drive. Now I can boot that by choosing that other drive as the boot option and get into grub there. I still don't know why the original installation process didn't install GRUB (or why it isn't loaded instead of booting Windows)

Comment: You _should_ have been able to install grub to the recommended partition nvme0n1p2 (EFI), where it _should_ fit into the EFI boot selection alongside Windows

Comment: The installation process certainly didn't output any issues, so yeah. It should have worked. I am contend with my solution of a different drive, but it is curious (and a bit annoying) nonetheless. My only idea is that some kind of windows repair restores the windows bootloader before GRUB is loading after restarting post installation.